# Sequences $p,p+d,p+2d,\dots,p+N\cdot d$ of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

A conjecture that I believe is possible to prove:

> For any $N\in\mathbb N$ there is a $d\in\mathbb N$ such that
>   $p,p+d,p+2d,\dots,p+N\cdot d$ all are primes (for some prime $p$).

My context: it seems that greater $\omega(d)$ (number of different prime factors) gives greater $N$.

Comment: Where $p$ is any prime number?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy: Well, an existing prime number...

Comment: See the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem)

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy It should've been "For any $N$ there is a $d$ and a $p$ such that..."

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, thank you. I had forgotten that theorem.

Comment: Courage, next time you'll win. If you continue studying and doing experiments with prime numbers sure that you can find more conjectures.

Comment: @user243301: Yes of course!  $\overset{..}{\smile}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been proven, and is called the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem).

And yes, the longer chain you want, the more prime factors you require of $d$. Basically, if you want a chain to be $n$ long, $d$ must be divisible by all primes less than or equal to $n$.

The only exception to the above rule is if $p=n$, in which case $d$ doesn't have to be divisible by $n$ itself. For instance, $$5,11,17,23,29$$ is an arithmetic sequence of five primes, with $d=6$, and since the first prime in the sequence is equal to the number of terms in the sequence, it works out without $d$ being divisible by $5$. But for any other sequence of five primes, $d$ *must* be divisible by $5$ as well as $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Thanks for the extra! I don't know, maybe I have drunk too much glögg (glowing wine), but a proof of the construction of $d$ above should be enough for proving the theorem then?

Comment: @Lehs No. You can prove quite easily that $d$ must be divisible by what I said, but it's not always possible to use the minimal $d$. Also, finding a $p$ is usually difficult. There's a reason this was proven fifteen years ago, not two thousand. Also, skål, och god jul!

Comment: Yes, that was what made me confused. Merry Christmas to you too!